# Need help identifying or reveres engineering a CRC

Tags: reverse-engineering, crc

I need help reverse engineering a CRC.  The application is the transmission of a date and serial number from battery packs to the central processor. I have found that the first 4 bytes  of line 1 contain a checksum or CRC, and line 10 also has a checksum or CRC.
The next 4 lines never change:

```
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
```

Lines 5 and 6 house the serial number and year.
Lines 7 and 8 never change:

```
    0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
    0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
```

Line 9 houses the date.
Line 10 has a 2 byte CRC or checksum.

I have nearly a hundred examples to analyze, and I have found several that have the same manufacturing date.  Of these, I have  a group of 3 where the serial number varies by only one digit, and a group of two that vary by only one digit.  I have tried using CRC Reveng while varying the format of the data.  For example I have tried running CRC revenge to solve for a checksum while including only the data that varies, and including all the data. I have tried it with and without the checksums without success. 
I have looked at groups of data for similarities in the CRC/checksums and found that the last byte frequently is 001A. 0018 and 0019 also frequently appear, and combined, these three appear about 75% of the time. In the CRC/checksum in line 1, the 4th byte is either 003A or 003B.

How can I tell if these are CRCs or checksums?  Even changing a single number in the serial number data will alter the first 3 bytes of the leading 4 byte CRC/checksum, and both bytes in the trailing 2 byte CRC/checksum. It appears that the desinger's purpose was to create a robust method of transmission of a weak signal in a noisy environment. Speed was not essential, and it may take several minutes for updated data to be accepted by the receiver. The method of transmission is pulse width modulation sent over the battery cables at about 20khz. I am unable to read that directly. I am getting my data from the transmitter's memory.

```
0069    0027    00FB    003A    0060    0003    0000    0000    00C8
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
0009    0040    002C    00F2    0055    0044    0031    0033    003C
0033    0031    0031    0030    0032    0038    0031    0036    00FA
0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
0030    0037    002F    0033    0031    002F    0031    0033    00D3
00BB    0019    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    007C

0068    0017    0000    003B    0060    0003    0000    0000    00D3
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
0009    0040    002C    00F2    0055    0044    0031    0033    003C
0033    0031    0031    0030    0032    0038    0031    0037    00F9
0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
0030    0037    002F    0033    0031    002F    0031    0033    00D3
00B1    0018    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0087

0013    00F1    0000    003B    0060    0003    0000    0000    004E
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
0009    0040    002C    00F2    0055    0044    0031    0033    003C
0033    0031    0031    0030    0032    0038    0031    0038    00F8
0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
0030    00037   002F    0033    0031    002F    0031    0033    00D3
0037    0019    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000

00EB    0091    00F0    003A    0060    0003    0000    0000    0000
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
0009    0040    002C    00F2    0055    0044    0031    0033    003C
0033    0031    0031    0030    0032    0038    0032    0030    00FF
0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
0030    0037    002F    0033    0031    002F    0031    0033    00D3
0097    001A    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    009F


00BE    0084    00F8    003A    0060    0003    0000    0000    0019
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
0009    0040    002C    00F2    0055    0044    0031    0033    003C
0033    0031    0031    0030    0034    0037    0038    0036    00F2
0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
0030    0037    002F    0033    0031    002F    0031    0033    00D3
0072    001A    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    00C4


0000    00C8    00F6    003A    0060    0003    0000    0000    00B3
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
0009    0040    002C    00F2    0055    0044    0031    0033    003C
0033    0031    0031    0030    0034    0037    0038    0037    00F1
0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
0030    0037    002F    0033    0031    002F    0031    0033    00D3
00D9    001A    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    005D


009D    0049    00FE    003A    0060    0003    0000    0000    006F
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
0009    0040    002C    00F2    0055    0044    0031    0033    003C
0033    0031    0031    0030    0034    0037    0039    0031    00F6
0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
0030    0037    002F    0033    0031    002F    0031    0033    00D3
0018    001A    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    001E

009D    0049    00FE    003A    0060    0003    0000    0000    006F
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
0009    0040    002C    00F2    0055    0044    0031    0033    003C
0033    0031    0031    0030    0034    0037    0039    0031    00F6
0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
0030    0037    002F    0033    0031    002F    0031    0033    00D3
0018    001A    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    001E



0090    00F7    00FA    003A    0060    0003    0000    0000    00D2
00A0    000F    0097    000F    00B6    0037    00F4    002C    007E
0065    00BB    0067    00AE    001C    00BD    0072    00DC    0074
00D9    003F    00B4    00D2    007F    00BC    00D3    00BA    005A
005D    0039    0000    009D    000B    00BA    0035    0063    003F
0009    0040    002C    00F2    0055    0044    0031    0033    003C
0033    0031    0031    0030    0034    0038    0033    0035    00F7
0000    0000    0000    0000    0053    0059    0042    0054    003E
0035    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    003B
0030    0037    002F    0033    0031    002F    0031    0033    00D3
00B4    001A    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0082
```

Comment: If these are CRC, you should be able to XOR two of the messages to get a third valid message, unless the CRC is post complemented, in which case, you'll need to complement the CRC after XOR'ing two of the messages. If these are some type of binary Reed Solomon code, again XOR'ing two of the messages should produce a third valid message.

Comment: The last byte of line 10 is also changing.

Comment: I  will give XOR'ing a try and see what happens.  i went through over 50 messages, and found that for the 2 byte "crc", the last byte has only 3 possible values: h18, h19, and h1A.  For the 4 byte "crc" there are only 2 possible values: h3A and h3B

Comment: What about the last 7 bytes of line 10?

Comment: I'm not sure if we are talking about the same line 10.  I am beginning at the top as line zero.  The bottom line I am calling line 10, and it has the 2 byte "crc"  The line above that has the date code. The last column in my data is the parity bit for the memory chip. I am not sure if that is being included in the calculation.

Comment: What's with the extraneous two leading zeros?

Comment: And why are there _three_ leading zeros on one of the numbers?

Comment: @Robertjf - on line 10, the next to last byte (calling the first byte 0 and the last byte 99, then the next to last byte is  byte 98) seems to be always 0, so I don't know what you mean by 2 byte crc.

Comment: The reason for the 2 leading zeros is because that is how the 93L66b memory chip is formatted.  The extra zero is a typo that occurred when I copied and pasted over.  I will ditch the extra zeroes and try again.  I am showing the data as it is formatted for the memory chip.  The last line has data only in the first 2 rows, and the last row is the memory chip's checksum.  unfortunately

Comment: I have been unable to reverse engineer the PIC microcontroller's program  that is sending this data via PWM to the central computer. I cannot directly read the PWM signal, either.  The only thing I can do is try different combinations of data and see if the central computer accepts it or rejects it.

Comment: Data with zeroes removed:                                                                          `69  27 FB 3A 60 03 00    00`
`A0 0F 97 0F B6 37 F4 2C`
`65 BB 67 AE 1C BD 72 DC`
`D9 3F B4 D2 7F BC D3 BA`
`5D 39 00 9D 0B BA 35 63`
`09 40 2C F2 55 44 31 33`
`33 31 31 30 32 38 31 36`
`00 00 00 00 53 59 42 54`
`35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`
`30 37 2F 33 31 2F 31 33`
`BB 19`